# SEO for rebuilding an existing site

Tags: seo

Question is if a single page webapp versus multi-page web apps is something to be considered when rebuilding any site. Interested to know what is going norm at this point by going multi-page website which is more SEO friendly and a single page website to have minimal to none SEO capabilities. It does come down to the strategy of what the site/projects want to achieve and in this case the focus is to do better SEO and have more relevant pages.

My gut feel is never to build product pages as single page web app as this will leave no chance to SEO multi level sub pages.

When referring to a multipage web app the aim is to reduce the sub-level pages into one single page where this page may have a chance to ranking for product names / product brands (if it’s an ecommerce site).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en#design_and_content_guidelines

Two things google suggest are to...

> Make a site with a clear hierarchy and text links.

and

> Keep the links on a given page to a reasonable number.

This means you're better off to make a multiple page website with easy to use navigation (especially if you want visitors) unless you have such minimal content where its no more than maybe a few poems.

If you're doing product pages, then have them linked from a page that lists brief info about the products. On each product page, explain it in full detail so it looks like its a real web page instead of just a stub.

Comment: Hi Mike, Apologies for the delay in my reply. Appreciate the reply and answering the question.